# flutter install apk results in INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, flutter

I have been developing and installing my apk on the android emulator, and on a physical device with no issues.

Then all of a sudden, I am getting an error when installing. The only thing I can think of that changed was I deleted and regenerated my pubspec.lock.

I build and install with the commands...

```
flutter build apk --debug
flutter instal apk
```

When install on a physical device I get...

```
Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
Install failed
```

When install on the emulator I get...

```
adb: failed to install /home/user/src/MobileApp/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package
/data/app/vmdl770003105.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml]
Install failed
```

I have noticed when I build, in ~/.android folder, a debug.keystore.lock file is created, but never deleted. I can manually delete it, but every subsequent build process creates this build file and does not delete it.

Flutter doctor...

```
✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Linux, locale en_CA.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /usr/local/flutter-sdk
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (11 days ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /usr/local/android-sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /usr/local/android-sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.17.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Lenovo TB3 X70F (mobile) • *JHD874JBNA73B • android-arm64 • Android 6.0 (API 23)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```